# Having an issue with setting up MySQLdb on Mac OS X Lion in order to support Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, mysql-python

So I am pretty sure that I have managed to dork up my MySQLdb installation. I have all of the following installed correctly on a fresh install of OS X Lion:

1. phpMyAdmin
2. MySQL 5.5.16
3. Django 1.3.1

And yet when I try to run "**from** django.db **import** connection" in a django console, I get the following:

> > > > from django.db import connection Traceback (most recent call
> > > >         last):   File "", line 1, in    File
> > > >         "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/**init**.py",
> > > >         line 78, in 
> > > >             connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]   File
> > > >         "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py",
> > > >         line 93, in **getitem**
> > > >             backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])   File
> > > >         "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py",
> > > >         line 33, in load_backend
> > > >             return import_module('.base', backend_name)   File
> > > >         "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py",
> > > >         line 35, in import_module
> > > >             **import**(name)   File
> > > >         "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py",
> > > >         line 14, in 
> > > >             raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
> > > >         ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/[my
> > > >         username]/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so,
> > > >         2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib   Referenced from:
> > > >         /Users/[my
> > > >         username]/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
> > > >         Reason: image not found

I have no idea why this is happening, could somebody help walk me through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy,

edit your .bash_profile (vi ~/.bash_profile) somewhere in that add the following line:

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib"

This line assumes your mysql install directory is in /usr/local/mysql/.

This will solve executing via python interrupter launched in shell (the .bash_profile exports the path needed by the MySQLdb module to load the ' libmysqlclient.18.dylib').

If you are having this issue with a Python IDE like PyCharm add the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to the launching module configuration.

I hope this helps :)

Also,

To fully understand this problem, read the following section:

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#importerror

This explains this error in detail

Comment: Ok, so mysql is installed into "/usr/local/mysql-5.5.16-osx10.6-x86_64"  
  
I added the appropriate line to my .bash_profile.  
  
And you correctly inferred that I'm running PyCharm, so I went into "Edit Configurations" under the Run meno and added "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/mysql-5.5.16-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/'" under ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES.  
  
However, I'm still having the exact same issue when I try to run the program via PyCharm...

Comment: (Also, I seem to be having issues with linebreaks in the comments...)

Comment: get rid of the single quotes in the value of the path

Comment: I'm glad to help. I had the same issue and it was frustrating as hell to get this to work :)

Comment: Use this to get a particular pyCharm interpreter/virtualenv going, however keep in mind that @asgard's answer solves the problem globally

Answer (score 5):

I found the following solution for this issue. It worked for me. I have encountered this problem when I was running python console from PyCharm.

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

Answer (score 1):

Install pip if you haven't already, and run

`pip install MySQL-Python`

Comment: Just tried that, no dice. It told me _"Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MySQL-Python in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg"_ 

So I used the "--upgrade" flag and it went through the motions, and it's still giving me the same error...

Comment: How did you install mysql? Have you verified that your mysql install is working properly and you can connect, create a database, etc?

Comment: I did, issue is not with mysql, it's with connecting mysql to python.

Comment: How did you install mysql? With a mysql install that was done using `brew`, pip will do the setup correctly for most uses (notable exceptions being some Python IDEs). Did you install the 64 bit or 32 bit version of MySQL?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I used brew, though I honestly don't recall. Is there an easy way to 2x check?

Comment: running mysqld --help should tell you.

Comment: mysqld  Ver 5.5.16 for osx10.6 on i386 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))